# Elastic Search Singleton Transport client across portlets

Tags: java, elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-6

Hi I am trying to create a singleton instance for elastic search transport client. The instance of the client was a singleton if the transaction is happening inside the portlet itself but when i ported/access the client on another portlet it's creating a new instance. Is there a way I can achieve singleton transport client even across portlets.

Below is the snippet of client class.

```
private ESTransportClient(){
    // private constructor
}

private static TransportClient _client = null;

public static TransportClient getClient(){
    if(_client==null){
        LOG.trace("ESTransportClient is null...............");
        synchronized(ESTransportClient.class){
            LOG.trace("Creating new instance for client..........");
            String elasticSearchClusterName = "myclustername";
            String elasticSearchIP = "myIP";
            int elasticSearchPort = 9300;
            String elasticUserName = "username";
            String elasticPassword = "password";
            boolean isAuthEnabled = true;

            Builder builder = Settings.builder()
                      .put("cluster.name", elasticSearchClusterName)
                      .put("client.transport.sniff", true);


            if(isAuthEnabled){
                builder.put("shield.user", elasticUserName+":"+elasticPassword);            
            }

            Settings settings = builder.build();                

            _client = TransportClient.builder()
                    .addPlugin(ShieldPlugin.class)
                    .settings(settings)
                    .build(); 

            InetSocketTransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(elasticSearchIP, elasticSearchPort));
            _client.addTransportAddress(address); 
        }
    }else{
        LOG.trace("ESTransportClient not null. Returning the existing instance of client....");
    }
    return _client;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these portlets in different webapplications or do they share the same?

Comment: those portlets resides on the same portal.

Comment: "on the same portal"... naturally. But are they deployed in the same plugin? Or in different plugins? (a plugin in Liferay 6.x is deployed as an individual web application to your application server)

Comment: yes in the same plugin.